# using LISTAGG in Orcale - ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Tags: listagg, ora-00937

I am writing a trigger that will insert a newly inserted row into another table by pulling up the data from the table using LISTAGG function. Here is the insert and select statement. I am getting ORA-00937: not a single-group group function error. Category needs a string with multiple values separated by ; . Is there any other way of getting category from JOBS_JOBCLASS,JOBS_CLASSIFICATION tables?

Here is the snippet:

```
 INSERT INTO jobs_tfour_data
    (
       jobid,
       title,
       reference,
       salary,
       location,
       department,
       grade,       
       opendate,
       closedate,
       description,
       internal,
       category
    )     
   select :new.jobid,:new.TITLE,:new.REFERENCE,:new.SALARY,LOCATIONNAME,DEPTNAME,GRADENAME,:new.OPENDATE,:new.CLOSEDATE,:new.description,:new.internal, LISTAGG(CLASSNAME,'; ') WITHIN GROUP (order by cj.CLASSID) as category
   from JOBS_LOCATION l , JOBS_DEPARTMENT d, JOBS_GRADE g,JOBS_JOBCLASS cj ,JOBS_CLASSIFICATION c 
   where  
   l.locationid = :new.locationid 
   and d.deptid = :new.departmentid 
   and g.gradeid =  :new.gradeid  
   and cj.jobid = :new.jobid
   and cj.classid = c.classid   
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

With oracle, you have to properly group everything, it's ruthless and will refuse to do anything at all until you do it "correctly", unlike the forgiving MySQL :D

So in short, as soon as you use one aggregation function, like in your case `Listagg`, you need to manually deal with the grouping. Just append the `GROUP BY` clausure at the end of your query.

For instance:

```
select :new.jobid,:new.TITLE,:new.REFERENCE,:new.SALARY,LOCATIONNAME,DEPTNAME,GRADENAME,:new.OPENDATE,:new.CLOSEDATE,:new.description,:new.internal, LISTAGG(CLASSNAME,'; ') WITHIN GROUP (order by cj.CLASSID) as category
   from JOBS_LOCATION l , JOBS_DEPARTMENT d, JOBS_GRADE g,JOBS_JOBCLASS cj ,JOBS_CLASSIFICATION c 
   where  
   l.locationid = :new.locationid 
   and d.deptid = :new.departmentid 
   and g.gradeid =  :new.gradeid  
   and cj.jobid = :new.jobid
   and cj.classid = c.classid  
   GROUP BY new.jobid,:new.TITLE,:new.REFERENCE,:new.SALARY,LOCATIONNAME,DEPTNAME,GRADENAME,:new.OPENDATE,:new.CLOSEDATE,:new.description,:new.internal
```

also, mind you using proper  (INNER) JOINS (aka explicit JOINS) would be nicer to read and to debug.